# How to prepare data for a many to one binary classification LSTM?

Tags: keras, time-series, classification, lstm, many-to-one

I have a time series data set for 38,000 distinct patients that comprises their 48 hours of physiological data with 30 features, so every patient has 48rows(for every hour) and a binary outcome(0/1) at the end of 48th hour only, the total training set is `(38,000*48 = 1,824,000)` rows .

To my understanding this is a `Many-to-one LSTM binary classification`, so should my input shape be `(38,000,48,30) (sample_size, time_steps, features)` and should the return_sequence be set to False to return output of the last hidden neuron only?

Can somebody review my understanding on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mostly you are on the right track. Refer the code below for a better understanding of this.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from keras.metrics import binary_crossentropy

# vocab size
total_features = 30
no_of_pateints = 38,000
time_steps = 48


model = Sequential()

# you can also use Bidirectional layer to speed up the learning and reduce 
# training time and here you can keep return_sequence as true
# model.add(
    Bidirectional(LSTM(
        units=100, 
        input_shape=(no_of_patients, time_steps, total_features), 
        return_sequences=True
    )))
# return_sequence should be False if there is only one LSTM layer. Otherwise in case of multiple layers, 
the last layers should have return_sequence as False
model.add(LSTM(
    units=100, 
    input_shape=(no_of_patients, time_steps, total_features), 
    return_sequences=False 
    ))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(
    loss=binary_crossentropy,
    optimizer='rmsprop',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

Let me know if you have any confusion in the above code or if you need more explanation

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot! will apply this.

Comment: @AnushaPrakash, if it worked for you, do accept it as an answer. So it can help other people as well.

Comment: @Abinav Anand Yes, definitely. Also, since I want probabilities for the binary classes, I would change no of the output neurons from 2 to 1 and activation to sigmoid. Sounds reasonable?

Comment: @AnushaPrakash sorry fpr the late reply, but you need to keep the output neurons to 2 because you would want to see the probabilities of both the output class not just one. And in case of classification problem, my personal preference is to keep softmax as actiavtion, but it totaly depends on you.

Comment: yes, I could do that and check which works out best for my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Why you dont use activation function in LSTM

Comment: @Talha by default, the api uses 'tanh' as the activation function, unless you want to use a different one, no need to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're mostly right:

- shape of inputs = `(patients, 48, 30)`
- shape of targets = `(patients, 1)`

You should use `return_sequences=False` in your **last** LSTM layer. (If you have more recurrent layers before the last LSTM, keep `return_sequences=True` in them)

Comment: Yes, I plan on using more than one recurrent layers. Thanks! :)